# How can I strip the data:image part from a base64 string of any image type in PHP

Tags: php, string, base64

I am currently doing the following to decode base64 images in PHP:

```
   $img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $s['image']);
   $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $s['image']);
   $img = str_replace('data:image/gif;base64,', '', $s['image']);
   $img = str_replace('data:image/bmp;base64,', '', $s['image']);
   $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
   $data = base64_decode($img);
```

As you can see above we are accepting the four most standard image types (jpeg, png, gif, bmp);

However, some of these images are very large and scanning through each one 4-5 times with str_replace seems a dreadful waste and terribly inefficient.

Is there a way I could reliably strip the data:image part of a base64 image string in a single pass?  Perhaps by detecting the first comma in the string?

My apologies if this is a simple problem, PHP is not my forte.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
$img = preg_replace('#data:image/[^;]+;base64,#', '', $s['image']);
```

if the text you are replacing is the first text in the image, adding `^` at the beginning of the regexp will make it much faster, because it won't analyze the entire image, just the first few characters:

```
$img = preg_replace('#^data:image/[^;]+;base64,#', '', $s['image']);
```

Comment: Perfect! Although all the answers are good and work perfectly.  It appears that your method is the fastest, therefore I will award you with the answer as soon as I am able.  Many thanks. :)

Answer (score 25):

Function `file_get_contents` remove header and use `base64_decode` function,
so you get clear content image.

Try this code:

```
$img = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA0gA...';
$imageContent = file_get_contents($img);
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. very smart solution!

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer, a much more elegant solution

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party, but this is by far the best answer.

Comment: Please try this, this is more straight forward!

Comment: Isn't this opening up for security threats?

Comment: this is ultra smart. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would have to test it but I think this solution should be slightly faster than Mihai Iorga's

```
$offset = str_pos($s['image'], ',');
$data = base64_decode(substr($s['image'], $offset));
```

Answer (score 0):

I generete a image with javascript/kendo and send this by ajax to the server.

```
preg_replace('#^data:image/[^;]+;base64,#', '', $s['image']);
```

it does not work in this case.
in my case this code works better:

```
$contentType  = mime_content_type($s['image']);
$img = preg_replace('#^data:image/(.*?);base64,#i', '$2', $s['image']);
```

Comment: Can you add a bit of explanation on why this works better'

Comment: I generete a image with javascript/kendo and send this by ajax to the server. 

    `preg_replace('#^data:image/[^;]+;base64,#', '', $s['image']);`

it does not work in this case.

Comment: Perfect, please add that to your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can Regular expression for remove image or pdf data formate.

```
data.replace(/^data:application\/[a-z]+;base64,/, "")
```